# is it able to override NSObject init method to add every object into a single NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, objective-c-runtime

I have a singleton object obj1, having a **NSMutableArray** member called *Objects*

and i added a category called *NSObject (Register)*

```
@implementation NSObject (Register)
-(id)init
{
    [[obj1 defaultObject] addObjectToView:self];
    return self;
}
@end
```

the *addObjectToView* method just simply add the object to the array

```
-(void)addObjectToView:(id)object
{
    [object retain];
    [Objects addObject:object];
}
```

(*Object* is a NSMutableArray)

the problem is, when i tried to test it, i did

```
NSWindow *window = [[NSWindow alloc] init];
```

and then i got 505 scary objects in the array,

[image]

did i do anything wrong?

BTW, it is possible to manage the relationship of all objects and send isolate objects *dealloc* message to implement a garbage collector in Objective-C ?

Comment: OMG! Garbage collector in times of ARC.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that!

This catches almost all objects created and prevents them from ever being deallocated. Actually even twice as you retain them manually and then add them to the mutable array which retains them as well.

Also you cannot override methods in categories. It sortof does work, but as soon as there is a second category that overrides the same method it's undefined which one will actually be used.

Implementing a garbage collector on top of that is not going to work either. Also you don't want a garbage collector. Apple used to provide one, but it is deprecated now and will be removed. Also you don't need it - use ARC.